# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.update

Tags: java, web-services, file-io, cryptography, heap-memory

I am developing a web application where I need to encrypt a big file approx 500mb to an image. First time the code works fine but after that my server gives an error **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**. I am using netbeans and glassfish server. I have also increased the heap size.

```
    byte j[] = key.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec kye = new SecretKeySpec(j, "AES");
    Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kye);
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("xyz.mkv");
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(output, enc);
    byte[] buf = new byte[104857600];
    int read;
    while ((read = file.read(buf)) != -1) {
        cos.write(buf, 0, read);
    }
    output.flush();
    buf = null;
    file.close();
    cos.close();
```

I don't know what's going wrong.Please help.
here is the stack trace..

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[DocEncrypt]: Servlet.service() for       
servlet DocEncrypt threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.update(CipherCore.java:666)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineUpdate(AESCipher.java:371)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(Cipher.java:1832)
at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.write(CipherOutputStream.java:158)
```

Comment: Please show us the stack trace.

Comment: @StephenC I have added the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stacktrace and the source code, it looks like the crypto stack is internally allocating a buffer whose size is the same as the same as the block you are writing with your `write` call.

You have chosen to use a really large buffer; i.e. 104,857,600 bytes.  So the crypto stack itself needs to allocate a very large buffer.

Solutions:

1. You could increase the heap size.
2. **Recommended**: you could reduce the buffer size to something more reasonable.  I would recommend 1MiB or less.  (Larger than that, the performance benefit you get from making the buffer larger is small ...)

Comment: it solves the problem but how can i make performance of  this algorithm better.

Comment: I can't think of a faster way, in Java.  Encryption is expensive.  You could try doing it using native (3rd-party) libraries or standalone native utilities.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you need to increase the maximum memory allocation pool for the Java Virtual Machine fe: `-Xmx2048m` when you start your application.

For more details check [this amswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/4780910).

Comment: Possibly.  It is also possible that he could do what he is trying to do with less memory.  For instance, a 100Mb buffer seems ... profligate.

Comment: hmm, but would using a smaller buffer change anything (memory-wise)? It would just create more smaller byte[] arrays which would end up being almost the same, right?. I don't think the GC would be fast enough to keep-up anyways.

Comment: Of course it would.  If you use a smaller buffer, that's a smaller heap node for the buffer.  It is not the speed of the GC that matters.  To a first approximation, it is the total size of all reachable objects that determines when you run out of space.

Comment: Ha! yes you are right, I just realized that the `byte[] buf` would be reused (I first though a new one would be created for each iteration...

Comment: as @StephenC suggested, a smaller buffer size would help a lot.